# mod_wsgi with python on virtualenv

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I'v compiled python 2.7.10 from sources with the following options:
--prefix=/path/to/alt/python --enable-shared --with-threads LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/path/to/alt/python/lib"

After this I've compiled mod_wsgi with the following options:
--with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7

This is how my httpd.conf file looks like

```
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/project/env/
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/src/project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/path/to/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /path/to/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I am trying to access my project from the browser, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/src/project/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/path/to/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
ImportError: No module named __future__
```

What can be the problem?